# binational map keeps smoothness?

Tags: curves, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $E$ be a smooth curve, that is, one dimensional projective variety with dimension one, and Jacobi matrix is non-singular at any point.
And suppose that the map $φ$, which sends $E$ to $E'$, is birational.
Birational means there are two rational maps on both direction which composites identity.

Then, can we say that $E'$ is smooth?

Comment: At first glance, I would say no: cuspidal cubic $y^2=x^3$ is birationnal to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $t\mapsto(t^2,t^3)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: No, this is far from being true. Given any singular curve $C$, its normalization $\widetilde{C}$ is smooth and the normalization map $\nu: \widetilde{C} \to C$ is birational.

Comment: Thank you so much. What about elliptic curves?  If E is elliptic curve, can't we say E' is always smooth?

Comment: No, my previous counterexample is quite general. Take any singular genus $1$ curve $C$, say a plane quartic curve with $2$ nodes. Then its normalization $\widetilde{C}$ is a smooth genus $1$ curve and the normalization map $\nu$ is birational.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your helpful comments.